# Why do these iOS7 Push transitions animate from top?

Tags: xcode, ios7

I'm seeing screen transitions in our app come in from the top right. See image below for example.

We're transitioning an iOS6 app to iOS7 only.

It was built a few years ago with XIB files, not storyboards.

We've enabled auto-layout, and this is standard views pushed onto a navigation stack.

Any help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What is the expected/desired animation?  Only right?

Comment: Yup, expecting standard transition.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like a plonker. These animations were hard coded into the app rather than using built-in view transition animations, so I just removed them.

Comment: If you've learnt anything, it's that animated gifs are a solid gold vote winner.

Comment: Haha, first time I've used LICEcap was for that, it is rather rocking for such things :)